Кнопка в телеграм боте не работает python
В моем коде отлично работают все кнопки, кроме одной. Вот часть моего кода:
        elif message.text == "Добыча еды":
            if forest_bool == False:
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Рыбалка")
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Охота")
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Лес")
                back = types.KeyboardButton(" Вернуться в главное меню")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выберите способ добычи еды: ", reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == f"Рыбалка":
            if forest_bool == False:
                global fish_spawned

                fishing_bool = True

                print("Рыбалка вызвана")
                fish_spawned = False
                map_cell = get_map_cell(cols, rows)

                user_data = {
                    'map': map_cell,
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 0
                }

                maps[message.chat.id] = user_data
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Начинаем рыбалку!", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, get_map_str(map_cell, (0, 0)), reply_markup=keyboard)
        elif message.text == f"Охота":
            if forest_bool == False:
                map_cell = get_map_cell(cols, rows)

                user_data = {
                    'map': map_cell,
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 0
                }

                maps[message.chat.id] = user_data

                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, get_map_str(map_cell, (0, 0)), reply_markup=keyboard)
        elif message.text == f"Лес":
            if forest_bool == False:
                forest_bool = True
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Перед вами две тропы. Куда вы пойдете?", reply_markup=markup)
                image_path = 'road.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
        elif message.text == f"Налево":
            if forest_bool == True:
                rand = random.randint(1, 3)
                if rand == 1:
                    if berries > 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        load_data()
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Кинуть им ягоды. В наличии - {berries}")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Попытаться убежать")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли налево и наткнулись на волков", reply_markup=markup)

                        image_path = 'wolfes.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                        photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    elif berries == 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Кинуть им ягоды (Нет в наличии⛔️)")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Попытаться убежать")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли налево и наткнулись на волков", reply_markup=markup)

                        image_path = 'wolfes.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                        photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                elif rand == 2:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли налево и попали в капкан. Энергия уменьшена на 1.")
                    image_path = 'road.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                    photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    energy -= 1
                    if energy == 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Рыбалка")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Охота")
                        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Лес")
                        back = types.KeyboardButton(" Вернуться в главное меню")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Энергия закончилась. Возвращайтесь домой!", reply_markup=markup)
                        forest_bool = False
                    else:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
                elif rand == 3:
                    image_path = 'berries.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                    photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли налево и нашли ягоду!")
                    berries += 1
                    save_data()
                    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == f"Направо":
            if forest_bool == True:
                rand = random.randint(1, 3)
                if rand == 1:
                    if berries > 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        load_data()
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Кинуть им ягоды. В наличии - {berries}")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Попытаться убежать")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли направо и наткнулись на волков", reply_markup=markup)

                        image_path = 'wolfes.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                        photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    elif berries == 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Кинуть им ягоды (Нет в наличии⛔️)")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Попытаться убежать")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли направо и наткнулись на волков", reply_markup=markup)

                        image_path = 'wolfes.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                        photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                elif rand == 2:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли направо и попали в капкан. Энергия уменьшена на 1.")
                    energy -= 1
                    image_path = 'road.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                    photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    if energy == 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Рыбалка")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Охота")
                        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Лес")
                        back = types.KeyboardButton(" Вернуться в главное меню")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Энергия закончилась. Возвращайтесь домой!", reply_markup=markup)
                        forest_bool = False
                    else:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
                elif rand == 3:
                    image_path = 'berries.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                    photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли направо и нашли ягоду!")
                    berries += 1
                    save_data()
                    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == f"Прямо":
            if forest_bool == True:
                rand = random.randint(1, 3)
                if rand == 1:
                    if berries > 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        load_data()
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Кинуть им ягоды. В наличии - {berries}")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Попытаться убежать")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли прямо и наткнулись на волков", reply_markup=markup)

                        image_path = 'wolfes.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                        photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    elif berries == 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Кинуть им ягоды (Нет в наличии⛔️)")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(f"Попытаться убежать")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли прямо и наткнулись на волков", reply_markup=markup)

                        image_path = 'wolfes.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                        photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                elif rand == 2:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли прямо и попали в капкан. Энергия уменьшена на 1.")
                    energy -= 1
                    image_path = 'road.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                    photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    if energy == 0:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Рыбалка")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Охота")
                        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Лес")
                        back = types.KeyboardButton(" Вернуться в главное меню")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Энергия закончилась. Возвращайтесь домой!", reply_markup=markup)
                        forest_bool = False
                    else:
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
                elif rand == 3:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы пошли прямо и нашли ягоду!")
                    image_path = 'berries.jpg'  # Replace with the actual path to your image
                    photo = open(image_path, 'rb')
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                    berries += 1
                    save_data()
                    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text.startswith("Кинуть им ягоды"):
            if forest_bool:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Волки от вас отстали! Количество ягод уменьшено на 1")
                berries -= 1
                save_data()
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text.startswith("Попытаться убежать"):
            if forest_bool == True:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы смогли убежать! Количество энергии уменьшено на 1")
                energy -= 1
                if energy == 0:
                    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Рыбалка")
                    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Охота")
                    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Лес")
                    back = types.KeyboardButton(" Вернуться в главное меню")
                    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Энергия закончилась. Возвращайтесь домой!", reply_markup=markup)
                    forest_bool = False
                else:
                    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Налево")
                    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Прямо")
                    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Направо")
                    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Куда пойдете дальше?", reply_markup=markup)  

Единственная кнопка, при нажатии на которую ничего не происходит, это "Кинуть им ягоды". Я уже проверял, что проблема не в условии if(т. к. Когда я поставил перед условием print, сообщение это принта не вывелось тоже)

нифига себе "часть", вы в своих IF-ах не путаетесь?

не путаюсь. Да и я не профи в питоне, поэтому все на костылях

Ну как минимум можно вывести в отдельную функцию создание кнопок, и эту функцию вызывать при необходимости, а не прописывать миллион одинаковых строк. А что б понять почему не работает нужно смотреть на ваши хендлеры, может у вас есть ещё функция, которая срабатывает при колбеках и в которой так же много if-ов, в котором какое то условие выполняется. Либо выше у вас есть какое то условие, которое выполняется. По тому что вы отправили можно сказать только, что нужно учиться писать циклы, а не дублировать кучу одинаковых строк

Можно весь код в студию? Я хочу это увидеть
